# vba splitting data into multiple worksheets when there are empty cells in between

Tags: vba, excel, split

Im having a problem to to track down data when there are blank cells in between . Im not able to track down data from k9 onwards as there are two empty cells k7 and k8. There are data from cell A to K. Cell K is the primary factor and name of the new sheets. Cell A to J are the other data such as name, time, office etc. Cell A2 to K2 would be the heading. The cell will be split to sheet A,B & C.

```
Department  <-- this is K2

A     <--- this K4
B
C      
       <---k7
       <---k8

B      <---k9
B

C     


A    <-- this is K14
```

This is my code

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

```
Dim ws As Worksheet, Rng As Range, cc
Dim temp As Worksheet, CostC As Range, u

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'where your original data. adjust to suit
Set Rng = ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 15)
Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1, 15) '<<add
Set CostC = ws.Range("k4", ws.Range("k" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

u = UNIQUE(CostC)
Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
For Each cc In u
    With Rng
        .AutoFilter field:=11, Criteria1:="=" & cc
        On Error Resume Next
        Set temp = Sheets(cc)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not temp Is Nothing Then

DoThis:

        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy temp.Range("A1")
        Else
            Set temp = Sheets.Add
            temp.Name = cc
            GoTo DoThis
        End If
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    Set temp = Nothing
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1

End Sub

Function UNIQUE(r As Range)
Dim a, v
If IsArray(r.Value) Then
    a = r.Value
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
        .comparemode = vbTextCompare
        For Each v In a
            If Not IsEmpty(v) Then
                If Not .exists(v) Then .Add v, Nothing
            End If
        Next
        If .Count > 0 Then UNIQUE = .keys
    End With
    Erase a
Else
    UNIQUE = r.Value
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Could you add a more detailed description of what you're trying to achieve? I'm not skilled enough to start debugging your code.

Comment: I am trying to split data in sheet 1 to multiple sheets based on the department column in cell K4 onwards. The problem that I am facing is I’m unable to track down the data if there are gap in between. Example the department starts from k4 to k100 and in between cell k7  & k8 is empty the program will only track down value from k4 to k6.

Comment: I got run time error 1004.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change this code:

```
Set CostC = ws.Range("k4", ws.Range("k" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
```

to this one:

```
Set CostC = ws.Range("K4:K" & ws.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

**Update:**

Based on your comment below, change this:

```
Set Rng = ws.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.Resize(, 15)
Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1, 15)
```

To this code:

```
Set Rng = ws.Range("A2:O" & ws.Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
```

I think we got problem on the CurrentRegion but i can't be certain since i cannot see the actual data.
Hope this works for you.

Comment: both lines are the same. if you do debug.print costc.address in both cases it will return the same addresses.

Comment: its not working. Im still not able to track down data from k9 onwards. If k7 and k8 have a value than it track down k9 onwards provided that it is not empty.

Comment: yep, figured. hmmm... I tried running your code and it does what you say it should do. It creates sheets for all non-blank cell value.

Comment: Do you know how to make it in such a way that it is able to track down data if there are empty cell in between?

Comment: that's what's odd. I didn't change anything in your code. It works fine.

Comment: Im getting the same result by changing the code that you give me. The problem is cell K cannot have empty cell in between.

Comment: can you try to debug print all `cc` in `u` just to check if you are getting all the values so we can check where the problem is?

Comment: Sorry mate im not sure how to debug print im still a newbie in VBA. I get this code through searching and modify it a bit to my needs. I think it work fine for you because you get the result as A,B & C in a new sheet A, B & C. The actual result you should get in new sheet A,B & C is two A in sheet A, three B in sheet B & two C in sheet C. As shown in the example above.

Comment: What's the value in `K3`? I checked and i'm getting 2 A in Sheet A, 3 B in sheet B and so on with headers.

Comment: k3 is empty. K2 is the department header the data starts from k4 onwards. Can i know do you have blank cell in between column K? If so then you are able to get the result. Can you share with me your code on how you improve it.

Comment: ah, i guess that is the problem. :) Problem happens during filterting. `K3` shouldn't be empty. try to put something in it, and re-run your code.

Comment: still get the same result it only track down until k6. K9 onwards are not able to go to their departments accordingly as k7 & k8 is empty. If k7 & k8 is not empty than its able to track down k9 same with k11 and the rest of the empty cell. But if k3 is empty it is still able to track down the department as it start from k4 to k1000  .

Comment: hmmm... that's really strange. Can you put this line `Msgbox CostC.Address` after you `Set` all your variables then put `Exit Sub` before `u = UNIQUE(CostC)`. Then run code. It should display a `Msgbox` with the address of `CostC`. Also check `Msgbox rng.Address` so we can check if the rng you are working with are correct.

Comment: I have tried and Msgbox CostC.Address which is in column K is okay for me the problem is Msgbox rng.Address it only track down up to cell A6 the non-blank cell in A7 onwards are not able to be track down.

Comment: I got $A$2:$O$6 in the messagebox when using Msgbox rng.Address. Do you know what is the problem?

Comment: now we know the problem :). See my updated answer. Hope we fix it his time.